# working with smarty and mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

this is the first time that I need to work with `smarty` and it seems quite straight forward.

however, there is *twist* in my PHP code and that is causing an issue.

here is what I am trying to do:

*Before you start beating me for not using mysqli functions etc, please note that this code is just a simple test for me to understand the smarty first. so i won't be using mysql in my project and I do not recommend anyone to do so...*

any way, here is  what I am trying to do:

I am using the following code in my `index.php` page:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
function isSubdomain()
{
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $host = explode('.',$host);
    $host = (is_array($host)?$host[0]:$host);
    return $host;
}
?>
<?php
// These are the smarty files
require 'libs/Smarty.class.php';

// This is a file which abstracts the DB connecting functionality (Check out PEAR)
include "config/connect_to_mysql.php";

$smarty = new Smarty;

$smarty->compile_check = true;
$smarty->debugging = false;
$smarty->use_sub_dirs = false;
$smarty->caching = true;

// This SQL statement will get the 5 most recently added new items from the database

$storeShop = isSubdomain();
echo $storeShop;

$sql = 'SELECT * ';
$sql .= 'FROM $storeShop ';
$sql .= 'ORDER BY `id` ';

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error());

// For each result that we got from the Database
while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 $value[] = $line;
}

// Assign this array to smarty...
$smarty->assign('storeShop', $value);



// Assign this array to smarty...
$smarty->assign('$storeShop', $value);

// Display the news page through the news template
$smarty->display('index.tpl');

// Thanks to David C James for a code improvement :)
?>
```

and this is the `index.tpl` file:

```
<!-- This is the DOC type declaration and links in the CSS stylesheet etc -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Steve Rendell" />
    <meta name="generator" content="EditPlus" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" title="Default CSS Sheet" />

    <title>News Page</title>
  </head>

  <body id="top">

    <!-- OK display the page header to keep it nice-->
    <div id="header">
      <span>Steve's News Page</span>
    </div>

    <!-- This is where the news article will be going -->
    <div id="bodyText">

        <!-- Have a title -->
        <h1 id="welcome">Read All About It</h1>

        <!-- OK this is a section which will loop round for every item in $news (passed in through from PHP) -->
{section name=storeShop loop=$storeShop}
   <!-- For every item, display the Title -->
  <h2 id="{$storeShop[$storeShop].id}">{$storeShop[storeShop].product_name}</h2>
  <!-- Write out the Author information and the date -->
  <h3>{$storeShop[storeShop].price}, {$storeShop[storeShop].details}</h3>
  <!-- Now show the news article -->
  {$storeShop[storeShop].details}
{/section}
    </div>

    <!-- Show copyright information etc -->
    <div id="footer">All Contents Copy Written :)</div>

  <!-- Close the html tags -->
  </body>
</html>
```

when I run the `index.php` in my browser, I get the following error:

```
Query failed : Table 'mrshoppc_mainly.$storeShop' doesn't exist
```

But when I use the following code, I get the right output which is the `name of the subdomain` and the `name of the table in mysql database` as well:

```
$storeShop = isSubdomain();
echo $storeShop;
```

and I know the table exist. P.S. the table name `$storeShop` is dynamic, so it could be any name that user chooses and it will be created in the mysql database.

I hope I explained it good enough for someone to be able to help me.

Could someone please tell me why I get the mentioned error and how to solve it?

I suspect this is caused by smarty as I never used to get this error before I started using smarty.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need your query in double quotes if you want the variable to be parsed. And since you didn't know that, I would suggest that you probably have a fair amount of preliminary learning to do before you tackle a database-driven website. Find a primer on PHP and learn about the way the language works. It will make life much easier when you're not fighting against gaps in your understanding of the basics.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw, Thanks for your reply and your criticism of my understanding of PHP after working with core PHP for 3 years. I assume you never made those school boy errors and have always produced a bug free, top noch PHP code. I only wish I could be like that for a day. :)

Comment: My intention was to help you, not to insult you. Of course, we all make mistakes, but yours seems to indicate that there are some basic language features with which you are not familiar. If that's not the case, then fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not parsing your string that contains the PHP variable.

```
$sql .= 'FROM $storeShop ';
```

To PHP single-quoted stings `' '` are literally what you have between the quotes.

`" "` Double quoted string will be Interpreted by PHP.

Try this:

```
$sql .= "FROM $storeShop ";  // OR
$sql .= 'From '. $storeShop .' ';
```

[PHP Strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Answer (score 0):

mis been a long time since i used smarty but from what i remeber there is no such thoing as:

```
{$storeShop[$storeShop].id}
```

you could use however:`{$storeShop.$another_storeShop.id}` 
if $storeshop is like array('storeshop_key'=>array('id'->'id'))

also `$smarty->assign('$storeShop', $value);` will create variable $$storeShop which is not correct

tips: print arrays in php before sending to smarty `var_dump($value)` and then in smarty use `{$storeShop|@print_r}` to make sure everything is right

Answer (score 0):

just remove

```
$smarty->assign('$storeShop', $value);
```

from your PHP code